# Change props value in function of window size

Tags: javascript, reactjs, media-queries, react-spring

I use React-Spring and i want to change the offset of some component when the window size change.
This is what i tried, but not working, and i always have to refresh the browser.

```
 <ParallaxLayer
          className="elements"
          offset={window.innerWidth < 576 ? 2.9 : 1.5}
          speed={1}
        >
          <h2 className="title-section Apropos"> A propos</h2>
          <div className="main-Apropos">
            <p className="para p1">
              dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate
            </p>
            <p className="para p2">
              animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum
            </p>
          </div>
        </ParallaxLayer>
```

should i use functional rendering ? or others solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Edit:

I think the problem is that when the window resize, it doesn't update the value and the offset doesn't change, what you should do is have a listener to see when the window resizes and save a state.

Here is an example using hooks

```
function useWindowSize() {
  const [size, setSize] = useState([0, 0]);
  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    function updateSize() {
      setSize([window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight]);
    }
    window.addEventListener('resize', updateSize);
    updateSize();
    return () => window.removeEventListener('resize', updateSize);
  }, []);
  return size;
}
```

And then just use

const [width, height] = useWindowSize();

```
return (
    <ParallaxLayer
        className="elements"
        offset={width < 576 ? 2.9 : 1.5}
        speed={1}
    >
    ...
    </ ParallaxLayer>
)
```

---

You can have a different approach or do exactly what you want.

The simple approach is having two classes with diferent media query values and simply toggle the classes.

OR

You could use [`styled-components`](https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components) and pass a prop with the offset where you have a media query.

```
const MyComponent = styled.div`
  @media (your media query) {
    offset: ${props => props.offset};
  }
`;
```

But... I think something is missing in your question, aren't you using `react-spring` ? Maybe you should be more clear on what you are trying to do and what you are using.

Comment: Thanks you so much for your answer, Yes i'm using react-spring and i want to set different offset when i switch to a resolution under 576px (mobile), because elements  overriding in mobile screen resolution.

Comment: I think styled-components is the best solution, but i dont know how to use them with react spring components without conflict.

Comment: @tedajophilippe what have you tried so far? What conflict?

Comment: I mean that "offset"  only work on `<parallaxLayer/>`, this i what i tried with styled component : ` import {Parallax, ParallaxLayer} from 'react-spring/renderprops-addons'                                                                              const ParallaxLayer = styled.div`
  @media (min-width: 576px) {
    offset: ${props => props.offset};
  }
const mobileSize = {
  offset: 1.5
}  return (
    <ParallaxLayer
        className="elements"
        offset={mobileSize}
        speed={1}
    >
    ...
    </ ParallaxLayer>
)` and i get a parsing error

Comment: this is what i get with the first option you proposed :                                                  
        `(0 , _react.useState) is not a function`